# how to redirect to another action in same controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, controller, action

i want to redirect to another action in same controller.
how can we achieve this?
i tried like return

> RedirectToAction("NotAuthorized");

Comment: That's the right way, what didn't work?

Comment: Where are you calling this redirect?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Add some more code to your question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName");
```

Instead of `return Redirect("/Elearning/NotAuthorized");` do this:

```
return RedirectToAction("NotAuthorized"); // if you're inside the Elearning controller
```

or

```
RedirectToAction("NotAuthorized", "Elearning"); // if calling from other controller
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeAction");
```

Comment: What fails here?  Does the View that you are trying to return actually exist?

Comment: ya view also exist i can go to that view

Comment: What's the error here? We'd need to know the error to help you.

Comment: i tried by putting debugger after excuting that statement it is comming back to previous view only

Comment: if (so.Count == 0)
                {
                    return  Redirect("/Elearning/NotAuthorized");
                    
                }

Comment: public ActionResult NotAuthorized()
        {
            int userId = GetCurrentUserID();
            ViewBag.ViewList = _menuViewUtility.GetViewList(userId);
            ViewBag.MenuList = _menuViewUtility.GetMenuList(userId, ViewSession.ViewId);

            return View();    
        }

Comment: @{
    ViewBag.Title = "NotAuthorized";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
</script>

<label>You are not authorized to access the selected resource. </label><br />
<a href="#" onClick="GoBack();"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GoBack() { 
       var Url = @Request.Form["RedirectUrl"];
       window.location(Url);
    
    }
</script>

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a redirect

```
return RedirectToAction("NotAuthorized");
```

is the valid way to do this. Make sure that your method actually exists.

Alternatively, if you don't want a redirect

```
return View("NotAuthorized");
```

works as well.

Comment: return RedirectToAction("NotAuthorized");    public ActionResult NotAuthorized()
        {
            int userId = GetCurrentUserID();  this is how i write in contoller..
            ViewBag.ViewList = _menuViewUtility.GetViewList(userId);
            ViewBag.MenuList = _menuViewUtility.GetMenuList(userId, ViewSession.ViewId);

            return View();    
        }

Answer (score 0):

try to explore the ControllerBase first, or go to the definition of the Controller which is what your controller inherits and then look for 'redirect'

Answer (score -1):

I am using asp.net MVC 3 and this works: `return Redirect("/{VIEWPATH}/{ACTIONNAME}");`.

Example, `return Redirect("/account/NotAuthorized");` where 'account' is your view path and your controller name is AccountController.  Hope this helps.